# Exporting to XML

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, sql-server-2008

Could you please tell me why the below sql has a problem.

if i run this part:

```
Select SmsSCh_ID AS "@Name", CONVERT(CHAR(10), SmsSCh_Scheduledate, 101) 
    + ' ' + LTRIM(RIGHT(CONVERT(CHAR(20), SmsSCh_Scheduledate, 20), 10)) AS "@Time" from Prj_SmsSch
for XML path ('Task'), ROOT('appSchedule')
```

I get the correct result but when i put it in the code so i can export the xml into the file i get error.

here is my complete code:

```
DECLARE 
  @FileName VARCHAR(50),
  @SQLCmd   VARCHAR(500)


select
  @FileName = 'C:\iman\SampleXMLOutput1.xml'

--in this command, we are making sure there is only one ROOT node

SELECT  @SQLCmd = 'bcp ' 
                + '"Select SmsSCh_ID AS "@Name", CONVERT(CHAR(10), SmsSCh_Scheduledate, 101) 
    + ' ' + LTRIM(RIGHT(CONVERT(CHAR(20), SmsSCh_Scheduledate, 20), 10)) AS "@Time" from Prj_SmsSch'
    + ' for XML path ('Task'), ROOT('appSchedule')'"' 
                + ' queryout '  
                + @FileName 
                + ' -w -T -S' + @@SERVERNAME

-- display command, for visual  check
SELECT @SQLCmd AS 'Command to execute'
-- create the XML file
EXECUTE master..xp_cmdshell @SQLCmd
```

what i think might be the problem is the ' inside @SQLCmd.
Error :

```
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 13
Incorrect syntax near ' + LTRIM(RIGHT(CONVERT(CHAR(20), SmsSCh_Scheduledate, 20), 10)) AS "@Time" from Prj_SmsSch'.
Msg 103, Level 15, State 4, Line 14
The identifier that starts with '' 
                + ' queryout '  
                + @FileName 
                + ' -w -T -S' + @@SERVERNAME
              ' is too long. Maximum length is 128.
Msg 105, Level 15, State 1, Line 14
Unclosed quotation mark after the character string '' 
                + ' queryout '  
                + @FileName 
                + ' -w -T -S' + @@SERVERNAME
               '.
```

Appreciate your help

Comment: what is the error message.Can you paste it in question

Comment: yes i did add the error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it with this:

You've muddled up the inner quotes. They must be doubled as they are *within* a string. Further I replaced your `AS "@name"` with `AS [@name]` 'cause the brackets don't need to be escaped. And after your `ROOT` declaration, there was one quote to much... Cannot test it, hope this works:

```
DECLARE 
  @FileName VARCHAR(50),
  @SQLCmd   VARCHAR(500)


select
  @FileName = 'C:\iman\SampleXMLOutput1.xml'

--in this command, we are making sure there is only one ROOT node

SELECT  @SQLCmd = 'bcp ' 
                + '"Select SmsSCh_ID AS [@Name] ' 
                +          ',CONVERT(CHAR(10), SmsSCh_Scheduledate, 101) ' 
                +            ' + '' '' + LTRIM(RIGHT(CONVERT(CHAR(20), SmsSCh_Scheduledate, 20), 10)) AS [@Time] ' 
                +   'from Prj_SmsSch for XML path (''Task''), ROOT(''appSchedule'')"' 
                + ' queryout '  
                + @FileName 
                + ' -w -T -S ' + @@SERVERNAME

-- display command, for visual  check
SELECT @SQLCmd AS 'Command to execute'
-- create the XML file
EXECUTE master..xp_cmdshell @SQLCmd
```

Comment: hi, Thanks for the answer but its keep giving me the error Error = [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]Invalid object name 'Prj_SmsSch'. The Table name is correct

Comment: I got it work by adding database_name.dbo.Table name.

Comment: Can someone tell me why its exporting in a single row everything? this is the sample <app><Task Name="10" Time="06/08/2016 10:25:00 "/><Task Name="11" Time="06/07/2016 08:25:00 "/></app>